# Help understanding about Series and Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I was hoping to see if anyone could help me out about explaining about Sequences and Series? Because I am getting bit stuck on how to really understand the concept of certain Sequences


Here's an example of a question:


Compute the following and show working:

$$
\Sigma_{i=3}^{40}\left(2i-1\right)
$$

Would anyone be able to help me out, and make it simple, so I can understand it??

Thanks

Comment: It is not easy to see what kind of answer to give, since it is not clear what machinery you are supposed to use. For example, the given sum is the sum of the terms of an arithmetic sequence, first term $5$, common difference $2$, last term $79$, altogether $38$ terms. You may know how to find such sums.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go!

A sequence is a ordering of numbers. In *particular* it is a function, $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$, where $X$ is some set. Typically we use $X=\mathbb{R}$ or $X=\mathbb{C}$. What this means is that we may associate the number $1$ and an element of the set $X$. Hence we get a sequence: $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$

Now a series is the sum of such terms. For example, the series above would be $x_1+x_2+x_3...=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$.

Using your example we may generate the sequence:

$x_3=2(3)-1, x_4=2(4)-1, x_5=2(5)-1\ldots x_{40}=2(40)-1$

The series of such a sequence would then be $(2(3)-1)+(2(4)-1)+...+(2(40)-1) = 5 + 7 +... + 79$. I believe you know how to add and may continue!